# Saving and Loading Array of Objects to Disk in Ruby and Shoes

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, shoes

I am making a shoes based Ruby GUI application. It includes only one class:

```
class Note
  attr_reader :text, :title, :color
  def initialize(text,title,color)
    @text = text
    @title = title
    @color = color
  end
end
```

And, an array of objects of type Note

```
notes = []  OR  notes = Array.new
```

What I intent to do, is to save and load this array to disk. Please help. I intend to do this quite outwardly without getting into the background details.
Marshal is useful, but using it with classes seems to be something of a headache.

Please help

Comment: You're not going to find a simpler solution than Marshal. Beyond that, you're looking at YAML, or ORMs like Sequel or Mongoid.

Comment: But marshalling classes is a heck of a job, the fact that you have to define `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods within the class and explicitly first convert each object into an array and then extract the instance variables from the loaded array.
I was looking for something simpler, like in C++, all you have to do is:

`File.read((char*)variable,sizeof(Class));`

and write similarly. Or maybe some database. Actually, I want to save and load quite implicitly without me having to specify all details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding marshaling capabilities is easy if you only export/import static data:

```
class Note
  attr_reader :text, :title, :color
  def initialize(text,title,color)
    @text = text
    @title = title
    @color = color
  end
  def marshal_dump
    [@text, @title, @color]
  end
  def marshal_load(array)
    @text, @title, @color = array
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend [`YAML::Store`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) from the standard library for easily saving and loading data.

You can see an example implementation of `YAML::Store` in my [pomodoro tracker](https://github.com/PragTob/pomodoro_tracker/blob/master/lib/pomodoro_tracker/models/file_persistor.rb)

You can just use it as a big hash where you have keys and put in objects, which are then correctly serialized/deserialized for simple ruby objects like your `Note` class. Code doesn't have to go into your objects, but rather the store.